# APEX 5.1, Set item values in column link doesn't like special characters... like comma or #

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

This is an APEX application to clean up address data coming in from a web form.

The user selects an entry from a list to view the address data. If the data needs to be cleaned up, they click a column link that sends them to an update page.

Item values are set in the Link Builder - Target.  But if the address contains special values like comma or #, then the item value is truncated, or ends up in the next column.

I've tried adding backslashes before and after the value in the Link Builder - Target window:  `\#street_line_1#/\`

And I've tried concatenating a backslash to the value itself.  No luck.  What am I missing?  Any other way to escape these values?

Comment: Why do you include a forward slash (/) before the final backslash (\)? It should work with `\#street_line_1#\`.

Comment: I don't have a "solution" for your problem, but - from my point of view - you shouldn't be doing that. Instead of using such a string while creating a link, I'd suggest you to use some sort of a key (primary? surrogate?), pass it to another page and perform query there to fetch data you're interested in, based on the key value you've passed.